# Why wouldnt this proof be correct? (Proof for compactness of a closed subset of a compact space)

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Let X be a compact space and $A$ be a closed subset of $X.$ Show that $A$ is compact.

---

Let $U_X$ be any open covering of X and $U'_X$ be its corresponding finite subcovering

For any $U_X$ define $U_A$ as {$C\in{U_X}$: $C \cap A \neq \emptyset$} which then is a open covering of A.

For any $U'_X$ define $U'_A$ as {$C'\in{U'_X}$: $C' \cap A \neq \emptyset$} which then is a finite subcover of $U_A$

Then A is compact because theres no open covering in A not contained by an open covering in X and then all open coverings in A have a finite subcovering

Comment: Usually, you tell us what you are trying to prove before you start the proof. Are you trying to prove $A$ is compact?

Comment: You've assumed all open coverings of $A$ come from an open covering of $X.$ This can be proved to be true using that $A$ is closed, but this has to be proved, and it is not true in general. Where have you used that $A$ is closed?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thats the error I wanted to spot, where should I use the closedness of A? About the thing I want to prove it's in the title of the question

Comment: You've proven every open covering of $X$ reduces to an open cover of $A$ (at least, I think that's what you're trying to say). This is true. As Thomas says, this is not enough - you need to show every open cover of $A$ lifts to an open cover of $X$. You claim this in your post, but you don't explain it or prove it. Focus on doing that, there you will see where $A$'s closedness is required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is assuming every open cover of $A$ comes from an open cover of $X.$

That is sort of the heart of the proof, but you need to prove this, and to prove this, you need to use that $A$ is closed.

---

Start with an open cover of $A,$ $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}.$

Now recall, a subset $U\subseteq A$ is open in $A$ if and only if $U=A\cap V$ for some open subset $V\subseteq X.$

So, for each $i\in I,$ there is an open subspace $V_i$ of $X$ with $U_i=V_i\cap A.$

Now, we don't know that the $V_i$ cover $X.$ But we do know one more open subset of $X,$ $X\setminus A,$ since $A$ is closed.

Show: $\{V_i\}_{i\in I}\cup\{X\setminus A\}$ is an open cover of $X.$

Then use the finite sub-cover of $X$ to find the finite subcover of $A.$

---

A simple example where your argument fails is $X=[0,1]$ and $A=[0,1).$ Then the cover $U_n=[0,1-1/(n+1)), n\in\mathbb Z^+$ of $A$ does not have a useful related open cover of $X.$

A related example is $X=\{0\}\cup\left\{\frac 1n\mid n\in\mathbb Z^+\right\}$ and$A=\left\{\frac1n\mid n\in\mathbb Z^+\right\}$. Then $U_i=\{\frac 1n\mid n\leq i\}$ is a cover of $A$ with no finite subcover.

This can be generalized in any metric space. If $A$ is not closed, there is some sequence $\{a_i\}_{i\in\mathbb Z^+}$ which converges in $X$ to some $x\notin A.$ We can use that to find an open cover of $A$ which has no finite subcover.

---

So, we can prove for metric spaces, we get the stronger result:

> If $X$ is a compact metric space, then a subspace $A\subseteq X$ is compact if and only if $A$ is closed in $X.$

The 'only if' part isn't true in general topology. Think of the trivial topology on any $X,$ which is always compact, and any subspace is also compact.

But we can prove:

> If $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space, then a subspace $A\subseteq X$ is compact if and only if $A$ is closed.

**Proof:** We will only prove that 'only if' part.

If $A$ is not closed, then there is an $x\in X\setminus A$ such that, for each open set $U$ in $X$ containing $x,$ there is an $a\in A\cap U.$

Now, given any $a\in A,$ by the Hausdorff property, there exists disjoint open sets $U_a,V_a$ such that $a\in U_a, x\in V_a.$

Then $\bigcup_{a\in A} U_a$ gives an open cover of $A.$

But given any finite subset of the cover, we get $\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} U_{a_i}$ is disjoint from $V=\bigcap_{i=1}^{n} V_{a_i}.$

$V$ is the finite intersection of open sets containing $x,$ and thus $V$ is an open set containing $x.$

But then there is an $a\in A\cap V$ and thus $a\notin\bigcup_{i=1}^n U_{a_i}$, so no finite can cover all of $A.$

Answer (score 0):

When you want to prove that a space is compact you want to start from an open cover thereof. You're starting from an open cover of $X$ instead of an open cover of $A$.

It is true that if $\mathscr{U}$ is an open cover of $X$, then $\mathscr{V}=\{U\cap A:U\in\mathscr{U}\}$ is an open cover of $A$, but you don't know whether *every* open cover of $A$ is of this form. Hint: the answer is no.

A different style of proof. A space $Y$ is compact if and only if,
for every family $\mathscr{C}$ of closed sets in $Y$ that has empty intersection, there exist $C_1,\dots,C_n\in\mathscr{C}$ such that $C_1\cap\dots\cap C_n=\emptyset$.

In your case a family of closed sets in $A$ is also a family of closed sets in $X$, because a closed subset of a closed subset is closed. The proof is complete.

Note that this *does* use the assumption that $A$ is closed, whereas your argument doesn't.